# Hover Not Working On Nested SPAN

Tags: html, css, hover, pseudo-class

I would like to change the `background-color` and `color` when I hover over the `#startButton`.  However, nothing changes in my current code (below).

```css
#startButton:hover {
  color: blue;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<a href='#arrow' class='startButton' style='background-color: #fff; color: #555;' id='brickButton'>
  <span id='theText'>Start Your Search</span>
</a>
```

Comment: `startButton` is a class, not an ID. IDs start with `#`, classes with `.`

Comment: inline style will always win the fight ... unless you fight with !important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all `#` is used for `id`...use `.` notation for element `class`

Also your code will not work if you used `.`, because the inline css comes first...So try to remove inline css and write it in separate css file like you have written `:hover` code...

Also no need to write the same css property on `:hover` if value is not changed like `background-color`

```css
.startButton {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #555;
}

.startButton:hover {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<a href='#arrow' class='startButton' id=' brickButton '>
  <span id='theText '>Start Your Search</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this CSS instead as startButton is a class not an ID.

```
.startButton:hover > span {
  color: blue;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Even with the typo fixed, this won't override the OP's inline styling

Answer (score 0):

change your css to

```
#brickButton>span:hover {
color: blue;
background-color: #fff;
}
```

or

```
.startButton>span:hover {
  color: blue;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below CSS:

```
.startButton span:hover {
color: blue;
background-color: #fff;
}
```

JSFiddler: https://jsfiddle.net/z34g50sc/2/